# SharePoint service configuration fails on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sharepoint, group-policy, windows-server-2008-r2, service

I am building a SharePoint test farm with SharePoint server 2007 Enterprise based on Windows Server 2008 R2. There are 3 different virtual machines (Hyper-V), all in the same domain, UCTEST. When I installed SharePoint and ran the configuration wizard, I entered a domain account (svc_sp) as the main farm / central account, which worked perfectly.

Now, in Central Admin, I try to go through the administrators tasks list, and in the assign services to servers task I try starting the Windows SharePoint Services Search service.
I enter 2 separate user accounts for the search and content access parts. The user's exist and are in the same organisational unit as the main farm account. But when I click start I get an Event ID 4625, audit failure.

The error message is the following:

> **An account failed to log on.**
>
> ***Subject:***
>
> Security ID:  UCTEST\Administrator
>
> Account Name: Administrator
>
> Account Domain: UCTEST
>
> Logon ID:  0x98828
>
> ***Logon Type:***  3
>
> ***Account For Which Logon Failed:***
>
> Security ID: NULL SID
>
> Account Name:   svc_sp_wsscontent
>
> Account Domain: UCTEST
>
> ***Failure Information:***
>
> Failure Reason:  Unknown user name or bad password.
>
> Status:   0xc000006d
>
> Sub Status:  0xc000006a
>
> ***Process Information:***
>
> Caller Process ID: 0x364
>
> Caller Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> ***Network Information:***
>
> Workstation Name: UCTEST-UC01
>
> Source Network Address: -
>
> Source Port:  -
>
> ***Detailed Authentication Information:***
>
> Logon Process:  Advapi
>
> Authentication Package: Negotiate
>
> Transited Services: -
>
> Package Name  (NTLM only): -
>
> Key Length:  0

**P.S.** Thinking it could be SQL related i have made all service account securityadmin and dbcreator on SQL Server (2008 SP1)

**P.P.S.** All users needed are added to the "logon as batch" / "logon as service" in the local security group policy.

Comment: are you specifying service account names the form of uctest\service_account_name?

Comment: Yes, fully qualified usernames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the user accounts and recreating them seemed to do the trick. Tried logging on to the machine as the service account didn't work, so i figured there had to be something wrong with the account. deleted it, added it, now it's all working again..

Comment: Another thing you might have tried in SCA to go to Managed Accounts and reset the password for the managed service application.  If you find that your application pool consistently quits when you access a page, this is usually what fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Check SQL Server to see if the svc_sp_wsscontent account has a mapping to the appropriate databases.

Comment: It is in the securityadmin / dbcreator server role, it shouldn't need any mapping. Furthermore, the only db's created are the config / central admin content db's

Answer (score 0):

By default local administrators have rights to access Central Administrator, but they do not necessarily have full control over everything.

Try logging into Central Admin with the farm account (svc_sp) or grant uctest\administrator farm administrator rights (Central Admin -> Operations -> Farm Administrators).

Comment: tried that already, this is going wrong on the windows level, not sharepoint.

Comment: then there is always the official documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx. Talks about all the accounts you can set up, and what rights on the server, in the db, and the in the domain they need.